# Is there any way to disable Tabs in ActionBarSherlock.......?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I got three tabs. When i click on one tab, the other tabs should get disabled. I tried modifying the Tab click listener but that not helping. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it is possible to do this, but I have 2 proposals for you :

1. Remove tab instead of disable it, by using method

> ```
> actionbar.removeTab(myTab);
> ```

1. Cancel action when user click on a disabled tab

   ```
       myTab.setTabListener(new TabListener() {

           @Override
           public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
               if (isADisabledTab(tab)) {
                   actionBar.selectTab(currentTab);
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

           }
       });
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the response...when we do 'actionbar.remove(myTab)' it removes the whole tab from the view. I tried the second proposal too but got into some other complicatons....i will try on the second proposal little more and hope to find a way...thanks.